# Question on proving the second derivative is 0

Tags: derivatives

[image]

So I tried solving this question using the Rolle's theorem but that only has information regarding the first derivative. Does anyone know the approach to solving this?

Comment: Can you add your work in the problem on your post?

Comment: Can you visualize the $|f(x)-\sin x|\le1/3$ property? What does it tell you about some values of $f(x)$? What might *that* tell you about a couple of values of $f'(x)$? What does *that* tell you about $f''(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that, applying your inequality at $0,\pi/2$ and $\pi$ you get, in particular, $f(0)\le 1/3$, $f(\pi/2)\ge 2/3$ and $f(\pi)\le 1/3$.

By the mean value theorem, there exist:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
c_1\in (0,\pi/2)\,\,\,\textrm{such that}\,\,\,f'(c_1)>0\\
c_2\in (\pi/2,\pi)\,\,\,\textrm{such that}\,\,\,f'(c_2)<0
\end{array}
$$

By the mean value theorem again (applied to $f'$), there is $d_1\in (c_1,c_2)\subset (0,\pi)$ where $f''(d_1)<0$

A similar argument applied to the points $\pi,3\pi/2,2\pi$ shows that there exists $d_2\in (\pi,2\pi)$ such that $f''(d_2)>0$.

Now, since $f''$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists some $d_3\in (d_1,d_2)$ such that $f''(d_3)=0$.